# Java, LeetCode and Nulls: How does Leetcode compiler handle nulls?

Tags: java

I have been grinding leetcode all day, so far 3 of the problems I did on Eclipse have worked 100% but when I run them on leetcode's IDE I always get null pointer errors. Here is a current example of my code and the problem I am currently doing: **138. Copy List with Random Pointer** , which is just supposed to copy a linked list but by value and not reference.

```
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    Node random;

    public Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
        this.random = null;
    }
}
*/

//MY CODE STARTS BELOW ==============================================================
class Solution {
    Node n, r, pointer, output;
    
    public Node copyRandomList(Node head) {
        //Handling weird inputs
        if (head == null){return head;}
        
        Node output = new Node(head.val);
        n = output; r = output;
        pointer = head;
        
        nextHandler();
        randHandler();
        
        return output;
    }
    
    public void nextHandler(){
        if (pointer.next != null){
            n.next = new Node(pointer.next.val);
            n = n.next;
            pointer = pointer.next;
            nextHandler();
        }
    }
    
    
    public  void randHandler(){
        if (pointer.random != null){
            r.random = new Node(pointer.random.val);
            r = r.next;
            pointer = pointer.next;
            randHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what problem this solution is trying to solve, and provide the stacktrace for the NullPointerException.

Comment: It would also help to provide the input that produces the NPE. LeetCode tries multiple different inputs, chances are your code cannot handle one or more specific inputs.

Comment: FWIW - it is (IMO) highly unlikely that Leetcode handles `null` any differently to any other Java implementation.  (You are asking the wrong question ....)

Comment: Just tried your code on Leetcode, a quick fix is to use `if (pointer != null && pointer.random != null)` -- this fixes the null pointer exception in your code (for Leetcode) and then you can go ahead and debug in Leetcode. Also, I appreciate the Leetcode grind! Good Luck!

Comment: As @StephenC mentioned, Leetcode does not handle nulls differently.

Answer (score -1):

I guess Java is not like C/C++, does not have passing by reference, uses passing by value. Probably, there is a bug in your algorithm. You can just use a debugger for that, even on LeetCode you can simply print things out.

---

We'd simply use a HashMap for solving this problem.

This'll pass:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final Node copyRandomList(
        final Node head
    ) {
        HashMap<Node, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
        return clone(head, map);
    }

    private static final Node clone(
        final Node head, 
        final HashMap map
    ) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Node ptr = new Node(head.val);
        map.put(head, ptr);
        ptr.next = clone(head.next, map);
        ptr.random = (Node) map.get(head.random);
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

Here is LeetCode's most efficient solution (which is better), O(N) runtime, constant memory:

```
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
    public int val;
    public Node next;
    public Node random;

    public Node() {}

    public Node(int _val,Node _next,Node _random) {
        val = _val;
        next = _next;
        random = _random;
    }
};
*/
public class Solution {
  public Node copyRandomList(Node head) {

    if (head == null) {
      return null;
    }

    // Creating a new weaved list of original and copied nodes.
    Node ptr = head;
    while (ptr != null) {

      // Cloned node
      Node newNode = new Node(ptr.val);

      // Inserting the cloned node just next to the original node.
      // If A->B->C is the original linked list,
      // Linked list after weaving cloned nodes would be A->A'->B->B'->C->C'
      newNode.next = ptr.next;
      ptr.next = newNode;
      ptr = newNode.next;
    }

    ptr = head;

    // Now link the random pointers of the new nodes created.
    // Iterate the newly created list and use the original nodes' random pointers,
    // to assign references to random pointers for cloned nodes.
    while (ptr != null) {
      ptr.next.random = (ptr.random != null) ? ptr.random.next : null;
      ptr = ptr.next.next;
    }

    // Unweave the linked list to get back the original linked list and the cloned list.
    // i.e. A->A'->B->B'->C->C' would be broken to A->B->C and A'->B'->C'
    Node ptr_old_list = head; // A->B->C
    Node ptr_new_list = head.next; // A'->B'->C'
    Node head_old = head.next;
    while (ptr_old_list != null) {
      ptr_old_list.next = ptr_old_list.next.next;
      ptr_new_list.next = (ptr_new_list.next != null) ? ptr_new_list.next.next : null;
      ptr_old_list = ptr_old_list.next;
      ptr_new_list = ptr_new_list.next;
    }
    return head_old;
  }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.